# How to use script to open an app if it's not the front most app, and hide it when it is the front most app in macos?

Tags: macos, applescript, command-line, bash, script

I need a script to open an app if it's not the frontmost app and hide(command+h) it when it is the frontmost app.

e.g 'Kim.app'

how to write this in Applescript or shell script?

Here is some info I can get:

Getfrontmost:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to get name of application processes whose frontmost is true and visible is true'
```

Open:

```
open -a 'Kim.app'
```

Hide:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to set visible of process "Kim" to false'
```

still don't know how to write this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
res=$(osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to get name of application processes whose frontmost is true and visible is true");
if [ $res == "Kim" ]
then
    osascript -e "tell application \"System Events\" to set visible of process \"Kim\" to false"
else
    open -a 'Kim.app'
fi
```

I did it like this, it works but excutes very slow, how to optimize this?

Comment: If this is shell script, then how is eval useful for the second and the third use etc? wouldn't it work directly ?

Comment: Even the first eval isn't strictly necessary, you can just run the command within `$()` directly.

Comment: In this use case, there is absolutely no good reason whatsoever to be using `eval`, it's just isn't necessary here!

Comment: Removed the unnecessary `eval`s.

Comment: Thank you, I removed eval, but the shell script still running slow(response slow),

Comment: You can run the steps manually to see which one is slow. Most likely the osascript calls take their time.

Comment: Also, replacing `'..."foo" ...‘` by `“... \"foo\" ..."` is technically a no-op, both versions work the same.